# SQL query issue with condition

Tags: sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT formam.*, SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME1.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME1.time_added
FROM formam 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME1 ON formam.ID = SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET WHERE SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET =''
    or SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET is null
    AND dyqani_pergjegjes=$dyqanip
ORDER BY formam.data_fillim DESC
```

The issue is, it worked fine but when i added the condition  `AND dyqani_pergjegjes=$dyqanip` it no longer works, i don't get any error though, i just don't get the desired result.

Someone help please

Comment: What's the type of that dyqani_pergjegjes field, what's the value in $dyqanip, and in general, would adding `'` quotes around the variable work, e.g. `dyqani_pergjegjes='$dyqanip'`?

Comment: any error message? Does `formam` or `SMS_MONTIME1` has a column named `dyqani_pergjegjes` ?

Comment: Have you tried adding parenthesis to make sure that the precedence of OR and AND is clear?

Comment: $dyqanip is a number type...
but it works on some queries, in this one it doesn't/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prolly fix the problem:

```
SELECT formam.*, SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME1.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME1.time_added
FROM formam 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME1 ON formam.ID = SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET WHERE SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET =''
    OR (SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET is null
    AND dyqani_pergjegjes=$dyqanip)
ORDER BY formam.data_fillim DESC
```

What I changed is that I put brackets around

> SMS_MONTIME1.IDTICKET is null AND dyqani_pergjegjes=$dyqanip

to ensure correct precedence of OR and AND.